# MVC 5 ASP.NET IEnumerable<Item> does not contain a definition for "Inspection" and no extension method "inspection" accepting a first argument of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to display certain data from my Inspections model in my Items Index view. They currently have a M:M relationship.

This is the error

> Error CS1061  '`IEnumerable<Item>`' does not contain a definition for '`Inspection`' and no extension method '`Inspection`' accepting a first argument of type '`IEnumerable<Item>`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any advice? Thank you

This is Items Index

```
@model IEnumerable<NCSafety.Models.Item>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Hazard Picture
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hazard.hazName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Inspection.ID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.itemCorrActionDue)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.itemCorrActionCompleted)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.itemComment)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @{
                    if (item.imageContent != null && 
                     item.imageMimeType.Contains("image"))
                    {
                        string imageBase64 = 
                        Convert.ToBase64String(item.imageContent);
                        string imageSrc = string.Format("data:" + 
                        item.imageMimeType + ";base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                        <img src="@imageSrc" style="max-height:100px; max-
                        width:120px" class="img-responsive img-rounded" />
                    }
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hazard.hazName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Inspection.ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemCorrActionDue)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemCorrActionCompleted)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemComment)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/Items/Edit/@item.ID"><div class="glyphicon 
                 glyphicon-pencil" style="margin-right:30px"></div></a>
                <a href="/Items/Details/@item.ID"><div class="glyphicon 
                 glyphicon-eye-open" style="margin-right:30px"></div></a>
                <a href="/Items/Delete/@item.ID"><div class="glyphicon 
                glyphicon-remove"></div></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
                    }

</table>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Inspection)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SchoolID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.inspDate)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
                    if (Model.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        <h3>No Records Found.</h3>
                        <br />
                        <a href="/Items/Create" class="btn ncBtn">Add Item</a>
                        }
                    }

<a href="@Url.Action("DownloadPdf","Home")"> Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: why not just change the model reference to something like this : `@model NCSafety.Models.Item` ? so that you can access directly each object model.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your model:

```
IEnumerable<NCSafety.Models.Item>
```

Then none of these will work:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hazard.hazName)
```

Because `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have any of those properties.  Perhaps you meant to drill into an *element* of the `IEnumerable<T>` for the properties?  Something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Hazard.hazName)
```

(repeat for your other properties)

Comment: If your view's model is a type of `IEnumerable(T)`, then `@Html.DisplayNameFor` uses an overload where the first parameter is `Expression<Func<T>>`. So you should be able to do  `model.Inspection` as the expression because T is an Item.

Answer (score 0):

Either Inspection is in the Model object or on the collection object that makes up the Model.  It probably isn't on both.

Comment: This is what I have in my models for ITEM to link the inspection table. Is that correct?

public virtual Inspection Inspection { get; set; }

Comment: @user2197867 I think you are on the right path.  Your model is IEnumerable<NCSafety.Models.Item> - that's a collection.  Therefore you can access only items in your collection.  E.g `foreach item in Model`. You can't do Model.Inspection, because .Inspection doesn't exist on your model.  It only exists on the item object in your model.